# AWS SAM/CloudFormation Template Lambda Delete Protection

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, aws-sam

We are migrating REST API service from EC2 to Lambda/API Gateway (to lower billing) using the AWS - SAM feature. This service is consumed only by internal application(INTRANET). We don't have VPN connectivity between on-premise and AWS. Each function is housed in a separate folder which includes a YAML file template. When deployed using the same stack name it deletes the previous function. We tried to use,

> DeletionPolicy: Retain

which errored out ,

> 'property DeletionPolicy not defined for resource of type
> AWS::Serverless::Function'

Our requirement is, to have a common base URL without using R53 (if possible).

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

[CloudFormation attributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-product-attribute-reference.html), such as [`DeletionPolicy`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-deletionpolicy.html), are not defined inside the `Properties` section. You may need to un-indent [`DeletionPolicy`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-deletionpolicy.html) so it is not defined within the `Properties` section

Comment: It is failing and rollingback. And I tried to remove the attribute and it  failed. I have to delete the stack and re-run without the attribute. :(

Answer (score 0):

I believe you don't need to retain the old lambda, it's fine to delete the old as you deploy new changes.

What needed is to tied the Lambda with API gateway.
In other words, your cloudformation template should have Lambda resources and for API Gateway point to the like

```
Uri: !Sub 'arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${LambdaFunction.Arn}/invocations'
```

within `AWS::ApiGateway::Method` resources

I quoted my code block from [AWS Samples on github](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-lambda-url-apigateway-cfn/blob/main/src/template_lambda_APIG.yaml#L195-L197)

In case you have different cloud formation templates you might consider to Output section in cloudformation templates to export resources